# For someone hovering near a black hole, how would he express the metric?

Tags: black-holes, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, curvature

If someone is hovering above a black hole (not infalling), his metric evaluated at his coordinates $r_*$ is flat (Minkowski), but more generally, for any r, how would the metric be expressed, knowing that as $r \to r_*$ the metric approaches the minkowski metric. What are these coordinates called?

Comment: The metric is only locally flat, when you have a free falling observer.